# My conditional GAN seems to be experiencing mode collapse

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I've been designing this conditional GAN in Tensorflow using the celebA dataset. It seems to be experiencing what I assume is mode collapse.

I have tried adjusting the discriminator to minimize Wasserstein distance but that did not seem to help. I also tried reducing the range of my condition vector thinking that maybe the noise was getting drowned out by the large values in the condition.

This is how I'm declaring my cost functions

```
self.fake_images = self.generator(self.z, self.y, self.phase)

real_result, real_logits = self.discriminator(self.images, self.y, self.phase)

fake_result, fake_logits = self.discriminator(self.fake_images, self.y, self.phase, reuse=True)

d_fake_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.zeros_like(fake_result), logits=fake_logits))

d_real_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.ones_like(real_result), logits=real_logits))

self.d_loss = d_real_loss + d_fake_loss

self.g_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.ones_like(fake_result), logits=fake_logits))

t_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
self.d_vars = [var for var in t_vars if 'dis' in var.name]
self.g_vars = [var for var in t_vars if 'gen' in var.name]
```